# CakePHP find() and related models and conditions

Tags: cakephp

I am calling find() on my Game model in order to get the reviews of that game for a particular platform. The problem is that the find() call doesn't seem to be paying attention to my conditions array. The call returns all the reviews for a game regardless of the platform_id.

I have these model associations:

- User hasMany Review
- Game hasMany Review
- Review belongsTo Game
- Review belongsTo User
- Game HABTM Platform

This is the find call that I created:

```
    $options = array(
        'group' => array(
            'Game.id'
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'reviews',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Game.id=reviews.game_id'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'platforms',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'reviews.platform_id=platforms.id'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'users',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'reviews.user_id=users.id'
                )
            )
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'Game.id', 'Game.name',
            'platforms.id', 'platforms.name',
            'users.id', 'users.username'
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'AND' => array(
                'NOT' => array('reviews.review_text' => NULL),
                'platforms.id' => $pid,
            )
        ),
        'limit' => 5
    );

    $this->Game->find('all', $options);
```

Here is a sample return for a find() call for platform_id=2:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Game' => array(
        'id' => '58',
        'name' => 'Bioshock 2'
    ),
    'platforms' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'PlayStation 3'
    ),
    'users' => array(
        'id' => '20',
        'username' => 'pspmaniac'
    ),
    'Review' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '32',
            'review_text' => 'This is the PC review.',
            'score' => '4',
            'user_id' => '20',
            'game_id' => '58',
            'created' => '2013-04-30 19:59:40',
            'platform_id' => '10'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '33',
            'review_text' => 'This is the PS3 review.',
            'score' => '7',
            'user_id' => '20',
            'game_id' => '58',
            'created' => '2013-04-30 20:00:04',
            'platform_id' => '2'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '34',
            'review_text' => 'This is the XBOX 360 review.',
            'score' => '6',
            'user_id' => '20',
            'game_id' => '58',
            'created' => '2013-04-30 20:00:22',
            'platform_id' => '1'
        )
    )
)
);
```

In the 'Review' index, it returns three reviews for the game (platform ids 10, 2, and 1) when it should only return the review with platform_id=2.

This is my `reviews` table:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews
(
   id mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment,
   review_text mediumint,
   score int not null,
   user_id mediumint unsigned not null,
   game_id mediumint unsigned not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
   FOREIGN KEY (game_id) REFERENCES games (id)
);
```

So, in the end, the only thing wrong with the returned array is that it contains reviews not only for the condition 'platforms.id=2' but for all platform ids.

Comment: It returns `reviews` that are related to the `Game`. So you should bind `reviews` to `platforms`.

Comment: Why are you using Joins instead of the [super-amazing Containable Behavior provided by CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)?

Comment: First, thanks Preetam for your comment. I was working on a solution using that when I looked back and saw the comment by Dave. Dave, I looked up containable and came up with the solution I wanted:

`$this->loadModel('Review');

$this->Review->find('all', array(
            'contain' => array('Platform'),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Review.platform_id' => 2
            )
));`

I haven't used SO much so should I add this solution to my own answer and mark as solved or should I wait for you to post your comment as an answer so that I can give you credit? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you want really. If you feel that without Dave you couldn't have found an answer, you can tell Dave (for him to get the notification, add a @ before his name when you mention him) to post the answer for you to accept it. But you could also post your own answer and give credit to Dave there

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Using Dave's comment, I came up with this solution to my problem using containable:

```
$this->loadModel('Review');
$this->Review->find('all', array( 'contain' => array('Platform'), 'conditions' => array( 'Review.platform_id' => 2 )
));
```